# In robot framework, How to display the variable passed in the Test Case keywords in the html report with actual value of variable

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, robotframework

my code is:

```
*** Variables ***
${language_a}    English

*** Test Cases ***
Change Language in Settings
    User sets ${language_a} in Language dropdown
```

The varibale is passed and scripts execute fine.

But the resulting html report displays the keyword as

"User sets ${language_a} in Language dropdown"
instead of
"User sets English in Language dropdown"

The variable substitution is not getting reflected in the generated html report.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to do what you're trying.
What you could do however is just log the variable at the start of the testcase like:

```
Log    ${language_a}
```